# Speed of Light (in a vacuum): Is it possible to have a vacuum that is "more of a vacuum"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, speed-of-light, vacuum

I'm not quite sure what "a vacuum" precisely means in the context of "the speed of light in a vacuum". Are, for example, electromagnetic fields present in a vacuum? Is there a concept of "temperature" inside a vacuum?

Is "the speed of light (vacuum)" the same $c$ as the one in $E=mc^2$? If so, then why don't we measure $c$ more accurately than "in a vacuum on the surface of planet Earth"?

In short -- what is, and is not, considered "in a vacuum"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed of light can refer to two things, the speed a light signal propagates, and the special, ultimate speed that shows up in the equations of relativity theory.

Inside a medium such as glass or water light moves noticeably more slowly than in a vacuum. This is because it interacts with the material. If one solve Maxwell's equations in vacuum - that is, no material factors present in the equations - one gets a higher velocity that is the same as the light speed in relativity.

This is not a coincidence. Relativity was developed to describe how physics could be entirely independent of the speed an observer is moving yet always observe light signals having the same speed. Once one works through the algebra one ends up with a theory that has a special speed, leaves the Maxwell equations invariant (or rather, [covariant](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/em/el4.pdf)), and the speed of light from the equations coincides with the speed in relativity. This is basically a mathematical result.

All of the above is classical physics, but quantum mechanics messes things up a bit. In classical physics vacuum is just spacetime with no matter in it. Quantum field theory makes the fields even in what classically would be a vacuum have some energy, and particle pairs can pop up and vanish randomly - with measurable effects. This is why there is a [Casimir force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) between two conductive plates close to each other: the vacuum between them in a sense has lower energy than on the outside. Indeed, [it has been argued that this affects the speed of light signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scharnhorst_effect) passing through the space between.

These quantum effects are tiny compared to normal matter densities, so they mostly matter conceptually. The classical vacuum is just space with no matter present. Which is of course an idealization since in practice there are always a few stray atoms or particles even in intergalactic space, but usually the effect on electromagnetism (or relativity) is minor.

Comment: Re: Casamir force: you mention the speed of light signals passing through the region of lower energy between the two plates -- let's call that speed c+. Is this region of "c+ space" at all distinguishable from a region of space with a lower gravitational field? Can fields other than electromagnetism cause similar "c+" regions? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are different sorts of vacuum. In Casimir vacuum there are less electromagnetic waves, so the speed of [light is conjectured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scharnhorst_effect) to be greater than $c$ in Casimir vacuum, but that is only from the point of view of an observer in normal vacuum. For an observer immersed in Casimir vacuum, the speed of light still would be $c$.

Comment: "Casimir vacuum" is not the standard terminology for this, you likely mean the [Scharnhorst effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scharnhorst_effect).

Comment: @ACuriousMind exactly.